# Using specific JDK version for non Java build

Tags: travis-ci

Let's say I have a job using non JVM language. For the sake of this question let's assume that it is R so my `.travis.yml` looks like this:

```
language: r
```

Now, some of the packages I use interact with Java libraries and I'd like to fix JDK version (specifically to OpenJDK 8 if that matters).

Java projects have some tools like

```
jdk_switcher use openjdk8
```

but these don't seem to work if language is not set to Java.

Is there any clean built-in way to handle this?

I can imagine combining apt and script that updates-alternatives, but I'd like to avoid this path, unless it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

After installing openjdk8, I used `update-alternatives` (not sure if this is necessary) and then exported the JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variables.  The relevant lines from my .travis.yml look something like:

`before install:
   - sudo apt install -y openjdk-8-jdk
   - sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
 script:
   - export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
   - export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
   - java -version
   - R CMD javareconf
   - R CMD build
   - R CMD check`